# How to properly build a query that filters what I need in mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I tried to understand the syntax of some mongo commands.

I have some arrays like this:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5404506df59600af7d285692"),
  "leagues" : [{
      "name" : "Nami's Marksmen",
      "tier" : "PLATINUM",
      "queue" : "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "23712130",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "Woodyx",
          "division" : "V",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(56),
          "wins" : NumberLong(83),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : false,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(23712130)
    }, {
      "name" : "Ziggs's Redeemers",
      "tier" : "SILVER",
      "queue" : "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-24f25974-63de-402a-a78f-bb7811f3b362",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "RAGEDEINSTALL",
          "division" : "II",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(58),
          "wins" : NumberLong(7),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : true,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(23712130)
    }, {
      "name" : "Heimerdinger's Archons",
      "tier" : "BRONZE",
      "queue" : "RANKED_TEAM_3x3",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "TEAM-b8dbeb70-83b0-11e3-b41c-782bcb497d6f",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "H Fettarme Vollmilch",
          "division" : "I",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(75),
          "wins" : NumberLong(4),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : true,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(23712130)
    }],
  "summonerId" : NumberLong(23712130),
  "region" : "euw",
  "updatedAt" : NumberLong(1413521614)
}
```

Thats the first document from the database. This collection contains like 100k documents like these. From these documents I want the only the following documents to return: leagues.tier : PLATINUM, MASTER, DIAMOND and CHALLENGER (there is no OR involved, only AND). And for the leagues.queue : RANKED_SOLO_5x5. All documents that match the query should be returned back the to front end of the client (I use mongovue). I tried to use this but it didnt work.

```js
{ leagues: { $elemMatch: { tier: "PLATINUM", queue: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"}}}
```

Because its returning other `'league.queue'` values too, while it should be only returning platinum and ranked_solo_5x5. 
My new criteria is: `leagues.tier : "CHALLENGER", "MASTER", "DIAMOND", "PLATINUM"` 
and `leagues.queue : "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"`.

**Wanted example output:**

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5404506df59600af7d285692"),
  "leagues" : [{
      "name" : "Nami's Marksmen",
      "tier" : "PLATINUM",
      "queue" : "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
      "entries" : [{
          "playerOrTeamId" : "23712130",
          "playerOrTeamName" : "Woodyx",
          "division" : "V",
          "leaguePoints" : NumberLong(56),
          "wins" : NumberLong(83),
          "isHotStreak" : false,
          "isVeteran" : false,
          "isFreshBlood" : false,
          "isInactive" : false,
          "miniSeries" : false
        }],
      "id" : NumberLong(23712130)
    }
```

Comment: An output example as you expected is helpful.

Comment: The output equals to all documents that contain RANKED_SOLO_5x5 and PLATINUM.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve just the **first matched element** within the array, you can use the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) positional operator in the `projection` document of a [`find`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query. For example:

```js
db.collection.find(
    // Query Criteria
    { leagues: { $elemMatch: { tier: "PLATINUM", queue: "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"}}},
    // Projection - get only the first matching element within 'leagues'
    {"leagues.$": 1}
)
```

However, if multiple elements within the array satisfy your query criteria, the above query will not help.  In such cases, you'll want to explore the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), which provides a way to de-normalize an array using the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator, which is very handy.  For example:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Split the array elements into separate documents
    {"$unwind": "$leagues"}, 
    // Specify query criteria
    {"$match": {"leagues.tier": "PLATINUM", "leagues.queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"}},
    // Group by id and reconstruct the array
    {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "leagues": {"$push":"$leagues"}}}
])
```

Comment: Dear, your command returns the following error message : `Command 'aggregate' failed: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB) (response: { "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)", "code" : 16389, "ok" : 0.0 })`

Comment: fixed it with adding `,  { $limit : 5000 }`

Comment: I use a gui mongovue, when using aggregate function, its only returning document trees. I need plain json arrays to be returning. We have to do this using the db.collection.find() feature.

Comment: @floppy, to avoid the max document size error, the best thing to do would be add `$match` phase to the aggregation pipeline as the first stage, so only a smaller dataset will be passed to the `$unwind` stage.  This also improves the performance of the aggregation query and is recommended practice.

Comment: @floppy, you can use a `$group` phase after the `$match` and reconstruct the array, so the results will not only match that of `db.collection.find`, but also only contain elements in the array that match the criteria

Comment: @floppy, I have updated my answer to include a `$group` stage to reconstruct the array.

Comment: @floppy, What's version of your MongoDB server? If it's 2.6+, you can save the results to a temporary collection by **aggregate**, then use **.find()** to get it by MongoVUE.